# Body size depends on resolution jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, var

want to create a dynamic website using jQuery scroll to .My elements should be very spread. I want to put them into an absolute position.

So what i want to do is that jQuery gets the window.width and height of the visitors screen . and multiplie the width*5 height*4 so my elements will be, where they belong. i can use a scroll to by anchor locallink # ..

Yet I'm not very strong in js /jQuery thats why I need ur help ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        var body_width = $('windows.width');
        $('body').body_width*5();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it with a simple html code with 4 boxes in absolute position right-top corner, left-top corner and so on.
 I added : 

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var bWidth = $('body').width();
    $('body').width(bWidth * 5);
   });
 </script>

 But the boxes stick together .. my resolution for example is 1440px, so after the jQuery script my body should be 1440 * 5 7200 px right ? and the boxes should be spread around the corners

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var bWidth = $('body').width();
$('body').width(bWidth * 5);
```